# Ruby on rails bootstrap thumbnail with link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I spent couple of hours googling and searching, but got nowhere.
Basically I have a thumbnail gallery with aviable categories, below each image in thumbail, theres category name. I want to ba able to clibk on that thumbnail and it then takes me to different page. 
I tryed doing this with link_to, but it ruined everything.
I pass @categories which has name, id and other stuff. My idea is to use id to then go to page with selected category id.

```
<%= @categories.each do |n| %>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
  <a class="thumbnail">
   <%= link_to products_path(selected: n.id) %>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
    <div class="text-under-thumbnail">
        <%= n.name %>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `link_to` block in this case.

```
<%= @categories.each do |n| %>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= link_to products_path(selected: n.id) do %>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
        <div class="text-under-thumbnail">
          <%= n.name %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If it worked, can you please accept my answer :) Thanks.